# Why won't the width of my submenus stay constant?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I can't seem to get all my submenus to be the same width as the "Meet the Team" menu. I've tried to define both `min-width` and `width` for `ul li li`, but neither seem to be working properly. Any help on the code would be appreciated, and I'd also like to know why the width properties won't work.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: center;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

ul li li {
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 100% !important;
    left:-70px;
}

ul li ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute !important;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

ul li:hover > ul{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

ul li a {
    background: #414a52;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 12px 24px;
}

ul li a.active {
    background: #0a304e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li a:hover {
    background: #0a304e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="active" data-filter="*" href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter=".web" href="#">Meet the Team</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Officers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consumer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FIGs &amp; REITs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Industrials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Technology</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a data-filter=".photography" href="#">Work Samples</a></li>
    <li><a data-filter=".product" href="#">Connect</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define link inside dropdown width, you use padding for that, in order to achive that you need to define dropdown links width to match parent ul and set parent ul width to match hovering item. I fix that you can see it on this link https://jsfiddle.net/Lhud8yv3/4/

CSS:

```
ul li li a{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
 }
```

Also i removed code from ul li li for margin and left position. Maybe you could use some class names to define menu and dropdown menus so you can access them easily using CSS of later on JS, instead of using ul li li a. I would suggest using BEM: http://getbem.com/naming/